# Set onclick to item that isn't visible

Tags: android, listview, onclick, cursor, adapter

So I have been looking around for about 4 hours now and maybe I just don't know how to word my search, but I am not finding out what I need.

I am using a custom adapter to setup my listview from items I have stored into an sqlite database. My cursor sends id, name, product_id, data, datetime to my adapter. But my adapter is set to only display the name, data & datetime.

I need to be able to click on the name, but have it go to my next activity and display the information from the product_id that was sent to the adapter. Example I click on Apples, but it would actually be product_id 505 in my database. Unless I set the product_id to a textview, when I click on my item, it does not bring up the correct listing and searches for Apples.

If this is not clear, please let me know and I will to explain it better.

** EDIT **

So my database is like this

_ID | PRODUCT_NAME | PRODUCT_ID | PRODUCT_DATA | DATE
1     Apples         505          Fresh Apples   123456
2     Oranges        506          Fresh Orange   123456
3     Kiwi           507          Fresh kiwi     123456
4     Nuts           508          Fresh Nuts     123456

My ListView shows this:
Apples- FRESH APPLES - DATE
Oranges - FRESH ORANGE - DATE
Kiwi- FRESH KIWI - DATE
Nuts - FRESH NUTS - DATE

When I click on Apples, I want it to return PRODUCT_ID to me, not _ID, so I can pass that product_id onto my next intent.

My Display listing

```
public void displayListView()
{
    DatabaseOperations db = new DatabaseOperations(this);
    Cursor cursor = db.getProducts();

    dataAdapter = new MainActivityAdapter(
            this,
            cursor,
            0);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.product_list);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    // listening to single list item on click
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long ID)
        {
            TextView listText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            String product_name = listText.getText().toString();

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, product_detail.class);
            i.putExtra("productName", product_name);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    db.close();
}
```

My Adapter

```
public class MainActivityAdapter extends CursorAdapter
{
private LayoutInflater cursorInflater;
private Context c;

// Default constructor
public MainActivityAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags)
{
    super(context, cursor, flags);
    cursorInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    c = context;

    // Log.i("Custom-Adapter", "Starting up");
}

public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor list)
{
    TextView PN = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
    TextView PI = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_data);
    TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);

    // SET OUR DATA FROM OUR CURSOR
    String pn = list.getString( list.getColumnIndex("pn"));
    String pi = list.getString( list.getColumnIndex("pi"));;

    // NEED TO RECONVERT DATE THEN SHOW IT
    Long millidate = list.getLong(list.getColumnIndex("dateTime"));
    Date myDateNew = new Date(millidate);
    String Sdate = getDate(millidate);

    PN.setText(pn);
    PI.setText(pi);
    date.setText(Sdate);
}

public static String getDate(long milliSeconds)
{
    Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance();
    cl.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);  //here your time in miliseconds
    String date = "" + cl.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + ":" + cl.get(Calendar.MONTH) + ":" + cl.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    String time = "" + cl.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + cl.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + cl.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    return date;
}

public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
{
    //Log.i("Custom-Adapter", "newView Started");
    // R.layout.list_row is your xml layout for each row
    return cursorInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, parent, false);
}
```

Comment: Where you set name to text view from bindView?  TextView listText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);

Comment: Please explain more because your question is not clear.what  values you want to get on ListView Click from selected row?

Comment: I want to get the product_id when I click on the name Apples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to get the product_id when I click on the name Apples.

We can achieve it in multiple ways but most common ways are :

**Option 1:**

Use `setTag` method for saving `id` of product with name in `TextView` :

```
  PN.setText(pn);
  PN.setTag((list.getInt(list.getColumnIndex("product_id"))).toString());
```

Now use  `getTag` method to get clicked product `product_id` in `onItemClick` :

```
String product_name = listText.getText().toString();
int product_id = Integer.parseInt(listText.getTag().toString());
```

**Option 2:**

Instead of getting product name from TextView, get clicked row cursor using Adapter in `onItemClick` :

```
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) dataAdapter.getItem(position);
String product_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("pn"));
int product_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("product_id"));
....
```

Comment: Option 1 worked like a charm, thanks so much. Sorry I couldn't explain it better.

Comment: @user3186578: welcome. i understand issue from your comments then answer.

Answer (score 0):

A good option is to create an array and store product_ids for all the names.

Goto Res->Strings  create an array of strings .

then fetch from the array the relevant product_id for the name.